# Aggregate functions on a single column only?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

**My learning goal:** is to find how to find an ingredient and see which recipe uses any given ingredient the most.

E.g.

```
+------------+--------------+--------+
| Pizza      | Ingredient   | Amount |
+------------+--------------+--------+
| Anchovy    | Anchovy      | 200    |
+------------+--------------+--------+
| Meatlovers | Pepparoni    | 150    |
+------------+--------------+--------+
| X pizza    | X ingredient | 50     |
+------------+--------------+--------+
```

Through:

```
(a) SELECT INGREDIENT,MAX(AMOUNT) FROM RECIPE GROUP BY INGREDIENT;
```

Works wonderfully, however I wish to know the pizza name of the recipe.

```
(b) SELECT NAME,INGREDIENT,MAX(AMOUNT) FROM RECIPE GROUP BY INGREDIENT,NAME;
```

Doesn't work as expected -I want the name to be appended to result set of **(a)**. Although, what I get is all pizza, ingredient, max amounts. I'm assuming the max function is applying itself to the pizza column as well, which I do not want. Is there a way to specify an aggregate function to only be applied to two desired columns and leave one (only for viewing purposes).

Comment: Can you add proper tagging to your question? Are you looking for a solution for MySQL, PostgreSQL, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSql supports [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-window.html), so the easy way is this:

```
SELECT  Pizza, 
        Ingredient,
        MAX(Amount) OVER(PARTITION BY Ingredient) As MaxAmount
FROM Recipe
```

Reading the question again, following Damien's comment, I think that what you are asking will not get you the results you want.

In the beginning of the question, you wrote:

> **My learning goal:** is to find how to find an ingredient and see which recipe uses any given ingredient the most. see which recipe uses any given ingredient the most.

Later you wrote:

> I want the name to be appended to result set of **(a)**

*These statements conflict.*

To know which pizza is using the most of a specific ingredient, as you stated in your first statement, use the **(b)** query from your question. You can order the results of it by ingredient, following the `MAX(AMOUNT)` column in a descending order - this will enable you to see what pizza is using the most of each ingredient easily.

```
SELECT Name, Ingredient, MAX(Amount) AS MaxAmount
FROM Recipe
GROUP BY Ingredient,Name
ORDER BY Ingredient, MaxAmount DESC;
```

The query in my answer, however, will get you what you what you are asking in your second statement - get the maximum value for each ingredient, grouped only by ingredient, but adding the pizza name to the result set. (In other words - append the pizza name to the result set of **(a)**)

Comment: But this will return *every* row from `RECIPE`. It won't help you identity *which* `Pizza` has e.g. the highest `Anchovy` amount (all rows for anchovy will show the `MAX`)

Comment: Yes, I know. That's what the OP is asking for, to the best of my understanding. I even started to write a comment to the question to explain that, but it turned out too long for a comment and not good as an answer.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I figured out the source of confusion and edited my answer.

Comment: Well, you can read my answer with my interpretation of what they're asking for. **(a)** gives them one row per ingredient. That + pizza name, by my interpretation, should still only have one row per ingredient.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Good point, I didn't think about it like that. +1

Answer (score 1):

A standard modern approach to this would be to use a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html) to assign row numbers:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Ingredient ORDER BY Amount DESC) as rn
    FROM
       Recipe) r
where
    r.rn = 1
```

This will arbitrarily select one row as the top row if there are multiple rows with the same highest `Amount` for a particular ingredient. To take more control over the query to break ties, add another `ORDER BY` expression within the `OVER` clause. In the alternative, if you wish to see all tying rows, use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Answer (score 0):

use corelated sub-query

```
   SELECT r.* 
   FROM RECIPE AS r 
   where r.AMOUNT =
                 ( select MAX(AMOUNT)          
                  FROM RECIPE r1 where
                  r1.INGREDIENT=r.INGREDIENT
                  GROUP BY r1.INGREDIENT
                 )
```